# Why does delaySequence() with concatMap() behaves like delayElements() in Flux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

#### Question

Why does `delaySequence()` with `concatMap()` behaves as `delayElements()`, so the delay occurs between each elements?
On the other side, `delaySequence()` with `flatMapSequential()` works as expected.

#### Background

There are two methods in [`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html?reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) to delay the processing:

1. [`delayElements()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-)

   > Delay each of this `Flux` elements by a given `Duration`.
2. [`delaySequence()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delaySequence-java.time.Duration-)

   > Shift this `Flux` forward in time by a given Duration. Unlike with `delayElements(Duration)`, elements are shifted forward in time as they are emitted, always resulting in the delay between two elements being the same as in the source (only the first element is visibly delayed from the previous event, that is the subscription).
   >
   > With this operator, a source emitting at 10Hz with a delaySequence `Duration` of 1s will still emit at 10Hz, with an initial "hiccup" of 1s. On the other hand, `delayElements(Duration)` would end up emitting at 1Hz.

#### Observation

When I call `.delaySequence(1s).flatMapSequential()`, it behaves as described above.

However, when I call `.delaySequence(1s).concatMap()`, it behaves like `delayElements()`, so a source emitting at 10Hz ends up emitting at 1Hz.

I cannot find anything in the documentation of [`flatMapSequential()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapSequential-java.util.function.Function-) and [`concatMap()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) which would explain this discrepancy.

The following Java code illustrates it.

#### delayElements() + flatMapSequential()

```java
@Test
void delayElements_flatMapSequential() {
    log.info("delayElements_flatMapSequential");
    Flux.just("one", "two", "three")
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .flatMapSequential(e -> {
                log.info(e);
                return Mono.just(e);
            })
            .blockLast();
}
```

produces an initial delay as well as a delay between each element, as expected:

```text
15:04:03.771 delayElements_flatMapSequential
15:04:04.975 one 
15:04:05.976 two 
15:04:06.989 three
```

#### delaySequence() + flatMapSequential()

```java
@Test
void delaySequence_flatMapSequential() {
    log.info("delaySequence_flatMapSequential");
    Flux.just("one", "two", "three")
            .delaySequence(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .flatMapSequential(e -> {
                log.info(e);
                return Mono.just(e);
            })
            .blockLast();
}
```

produces an initial delay and no delay between each element, as expected:

```text
15:04:10.036 delaySequence_flatMapSequential
15:04:11.047 one      <- EXPECTED DELAY
15:04:11.047 two      <- NO DELAY
15:04:11.047 three    <- NO DELAY
```

#### delaySequence() + concatMap()

```java
@Test
void delaySequence_concatMap() {
    log.info("delaySequence_concatMap");
    Flux.just("one", "two", "three")
            .delaySequence(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .concatMap(e -> {
                log.info(e);
                return Mono.just(e);
            })
            .blockLast();
}
```

produces an initial delay as well as a delay between each element, as NOT expected:

```text
15:04:06.997 delaySequence_concatMap 
15:04:08.016 one      <- EXPECTED DELAY
15:04:09.027 two      <- UNEXPECTED DELAY
15:04:10.033 three    <- UNEXPECTED DELAY
```